# Relation between two statements in representation theory

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

I have solved the following two problems in representation theory:

1: For $X=G$ with the action of the finite group $G$ by left multiplication, the vector space of invariants $(Fun(X,\mathbb{C}))^G$ is one-dimensional with basis $f\equiv 1$

2: That for any representation of $G$ the vector space $M^*$ is isomorphic to $Hom_G(M,Fun(G,\mathbb{C}))$ (where $M$ is a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module/representation of $G$)

My intuition tells me that these results are related, but I can't put a finger on why.
Does 2 somehow generalize 1 (or the other way around), or is my intuition wrong?

Comment: The second one generalizes the first one if you take $M$ to be the trivial representation.

Comment: So $\mathbb{C}^G\cong Hom(\mathbb{C}_{triv},\mathbb{C})
\cong Hom_G(\mathbb{C}_{triv},Fun(G,\mathbb{C}))
\cong (Fun(G,\mathbb{C}))^G$ with $\mathbb{C}^G$ being one-dimensional? I have a feeling I'm still a bit off.

Comment: The first line should just be $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ but other than that, yes.